# Graph Execution Error message using keras while fitting a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When fitting a model provided in book "Deep Learning with Python", chapter 8, using the following code:

````
callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="convnet_from_scratch.keras",
        save_best_only=True,
        monitor="val_loss")
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    callbacks=callbacks)```

Colab throws the following error message:
````

### Epoch 1/30
46/63 [====================>.........] - ETA: 47s - loss: 0.6821 - accuracy: 0.5673

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(
2     train_dataset,
3     epochs=30,
4     validation_data=validation_dataset,
5     callbacks=callbacks)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50   try:
51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Input is empty.
[[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
[[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1503]

```
Having no Error referenced in the tutorial's code, I have no clue to understand how to deal with it and solve it.
```